# Matlab image stabilization by fixed point in the video

Tags: matlab, fixed-point, image-stabilization

I am trying to eliminate shaking of camera in my experiment setup. I have fixed points in my video. I would like to use these fixed points to eliminate vibration of camera by matlab.. Where should I start from? Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: What are your fixed points? Do you have code to identify them? Do you want to maintain the entire image or just in some box / where the final images overlap?

Comment: Fixed points are dots marked by pen on the edge of the device. I want to see center of the images after sanitizing the camera vibration.

Comment: Do you have code to identify them?

Comment: Not yet, but I can identify them easily.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for start?

Comment: Identifying by eye and getting a program to identify them are two very different things. It looks like there is a function `imfindcircles` that you may want to look into.

Comment: Sorry for misleasing you. I meant I can track dots and get their motion vectors through matlab. I wrote some code about it before. I am just wondering if there is a well known way to stabilize a video using some fixed point on it.

Comment: This is where my question about wanting the entire image, just a box, or where the images overlap. And you do have at least two correct? For all three you will need to pre-process and find the location of your dots in each image. Then translate and rotate so the dots are in the same coordinates. This is where you need to make a choice on whether to pad or cut. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to pad the view. Do you have any sample code that allows points to stay in same coordinates?

Comment: No this isn't my area of expertise. If you post a couple of images and your point recognition function, I'll try and come up with something though.

Answer (score 1):

this task can be faced using a tool called image registration. In the very simple sense, the registration consists in align two images as best as possible. In this case the points that you have could be used as the features to achieve the registration of every single frame with respect one main frame, you can check it out this: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/image-registration.html . I hope this could be useful to you, sorry for the bad grammar, non native speaker.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I found DIC tool. I believe it will work for me.Do you have any experience with DIC?

Comment: Well, DIC could be useful when you only wish find the translation of an image respect other over the horizontal and vertical axes, but if you have some issues related to rotations or changes of scale this could be kind of harder using DIC